# SQL to compare date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server need to check if result from a select is some date in the where clause.

Tried this doing below. but failed. Need help with the same.

```
(SELECT FLDMODDATE 
 FROM EMPLOYEE 
 WHERE FLDRECNUMBER = 432893)  = '2019-02-05'
```

Comment: Add `AND FLDMODDATE = '20190205'` to the `WHERE`?

Comment: can't do that the way the sql is I have to do the select in where. Is that possible?

Comment: `where (select TOP 1 FLDMODDATE from EMPLOYEE where FLDRECNUMBER = 432893)  = '2019-02-05'` assuming EMPLOYEE isn't joined to your main query. You should show the whole query.

Comment: Seems like we only have one piece of the puzzle then. Can you expand on what you're actually after here. Is that a subquery within another query? If so, why haven't you supplied that SQL?

Comment: Thanks, for your help got it. I just had to put >=

Comment: Glad you figured it out but this question is horrible. Nobody can help when you don't post any information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select (case when exists (SELECT 1 
                          FROM EMPLOYEE 
                          WHERE FLDRECNUMBER = 432893 and FLDMODDATE  = '2019-02-05'
                         )
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end)
```

Or, if this is in T-SQL code:

```
 if exists (SELECT 1 
            FROM EMPLOYEE 
            WHERE FLDRECNUMBER = 432893 and FLDMODDATE  = '2019-02-05'
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `IF` of some sort.

```
IF (select FLDMODDATE from EMPLOYEE where FLDRECNUMBER = 432893)  = '2019-02-05'
BEGIN
    <Code here to do something>
END
```